# Matrix integration just spits out the inputs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, finite-element-method

I just started to use Mathematica two days ago. I am trying to solve a stiffness (K) matrix of a 4-node is-parametric truss element for my exam on next Monday. The integrand is a 4 by 4 matrix with only one variable s (ξ).

Here is my code:

```
N1[s_] := -0.561 (s + 0.33) (s - 0.33) (s - 1);
N2[s_] := 1.7 (s + 1) (s - 0.33) (s - 1);
N3[s_] := -1.7 (s + 1) (s + 0.33) (s - 1);
N4[s_] := 0.561 (s + 1) (s + 0.33) (s - 0.33);

Nmatrix = {{N1[s]}, {N2[s]}, {N3[s]}, {N4[s]}};

x1 = 0; x2 = 1; x3 = 2; x4 = 3;

x[s_, x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] = 
  Total[Nmatrix*{{x1}, {x2}, {x3}, {x4}}] // Simplify;

J = D[x[s, x1, x2, x3, x4], s] // Simplify;
Jinv = Row[1/J];

Bmatrix = {{N1'[s]}, {N2'[s]}, {N3'[s]}, {N4'[s]}};
Simplify[Bmatrix // MatrixForm];

BmatrixTr = Transpose[Bmatrix];
Simplify[BmatrixTr // MatrixForm];

Ao = Row[(0.1*0.1) (x[s, x1, x2, x3, x4] + 1)^2]
Ax = (2*0.1) (2*0.1);
EM = 180*10^6;

K = Integrate[((Bmatrix.BmatrixTr)*Ao*EM*Jinv), {s, -1, -0.3333}] + 
   Integrate[((Bmatrix.BmatrixTr)*Ax*EM*Jinv), {s, -0.3333, -1}];
Simplify[K // MatrixForm]
```

I'm getting a nicely formatted text. How can I get it evaluate?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One problem is that your variable called Nmatrix is not a matrix, but a list that is 4 elements long.

Comment: It was supposed to be a 4 by 1 matrix. I thought the matrix is formed by using the brackets? Please enlighten me.

Comment: All you need is: Nmatrix = {N1[s], N2[s], N3[s], N4[s]};

Comment: Remove the MatrixForm commands... those are for pretty printing results, not for creating matrices.

Comment: Noted. I do know the MatrixForm commands are for printing. I need it for showing the steps when answering.

Comment: I just tried Integrate[Jinv, {s, -1, -0.3333}] but it still didn't evaluate. I wonder why? Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: See bill s comments. Guessing N are shape functions. Not sure you are forming the stiffness matrix properly. If you want a 4x4 matrix from two 4x1 vectors, you have to use the KroneckerProduct function or related. I think that is what you are trying to do with your Bmatrix*BmatrixTr operation, but don't think that is giving you a 4x4. Could you provide a little more detail about what your various symbols mean. A little more clarity on what you are trying to accomplish with Total. The use of Row is confusing and likely incorrect, as it is a display command, much like MatrixForm or Grid.

Comment: Try `Integrate[Outer[Times, {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s], N4'[s]}, {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s], 
  N4'[s]}],{s,,}]` to get the stiffnessmatrix.

Comment: @Bill Noted thanks. The reason I add Row is because it can't get the multiplication with (Bmatrix.BmatrixTr) without it. But once I add it I can't get Mathematica to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @PaulCommentary You're right! N are the shape functions B are the deformation matrix. Ao and Ax are the area functions, the cross-section varies with length. EM is the Young's modulus. J is the inverse of Jacobian. The use of total is to convert/relate shape func to global coordinate and sub the global coordinate of each node into the shape functions to get J.

Comment: @PaulCommentary The reason I use Row is because without it I can't get the multiplication of (Bmatrix.BmatrixTr) with Ao and Jinv. But when I include it Mathematica won't evaluate the integrals. I'm so new to Mathematica, sorry if I did silly mistake.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How can get the multiplication of {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s], N4'[s]}, {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s], N4'[s]} with inverse of Jacobian (Jinv) and area function (Ax) and Young's modulus (EM)? Just add {} with the variables?

Comment: @andrewpete  Try `Integrate[Outer[Times, {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s], N4'[s]}, {N1'[s], N2'[s], N3'[s],    N4'[s]}].Jinv (Ao*EM),{s,,}]`  . But I don't understand your way to calculate `Jinv`...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks. Cause x is formed by summing the shape function and times x for each N and J=dx/dξ and thereby Jinv=1/J.

Comment: @andrewpete `1/J` isn't correct, try `Inverse[J]` !

Comment: Outer[] and KroneckerProduct are related. Show your results instead ending with;  It will help you see. Row is only a display command.